# Open an .html file with default browser using Bash on Mac

Tags: html, macos, bash, browser, applescript

So, this is what I need :

Let's say I have an `index.html` file.

How do I tell the terminal to open it using the default browser?

(Using AppleScript, BASH,...?)

Answer (score 112):

from the directory containing index.html, try...

```
open ./index.html
```

the open command opens a file (or directory, or URL). open is included with MacOSx. specifics and options can be found using

```
man open
```

note: default application is determined via LaunchServices.

Comment: That will open the HTML file in the default **editor or viewer**, which is not guaranteed to be the browser. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10250717/990363) for a solution that works no matter what.

Comment: this was the simplest answer that is also correct, in case anyone stumbles upon this.

Comment: better to serve it on localhost server and then :
open http :// localhost:xxxx  => ( xxxx = any port number 9000 / 7000)

Answer (score 35):

You can use the open command with the -a flag to open a file or location in Chrome (or any target application):

`open -a "Google Chrome" index.html`

This also works with URLs, i.e. open -a "Google Chrome" http://www.apple.com.

---> I found this answer @ [stack exchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83630/create-a-termnial-command-to-open-file-with-chrome), thanks to user "robmathers"

Comment: The requirement was to use the `Default browser`, so by specifying Google Chrome, you have failed to meet the requirements.

Comment: I agree, but the informationis relevant insightful, if also peripheral

Comment: and if you have local server then use : 
open http: // localhost:xxxx
xxxx = any port like 9000 or 8000 or any

Answer (score 22):

Actually, this is not quite as straightforward as it looks. As suggested by the other answers, OS X provides the `open` utility to launch applications matching a file type from the shell. However, in the case of a HTML file, that is the application registered with Launch Services for the **file type `public.html`**, which can, but need not be, your default browser (I think it is on a pristine install) – or whatever editor registers as able to edit HTML (not an uncommon occurrence on a dev system). And while the default browser is registered for the **URL protocol `http`** no matter what, there is no way to access that protocol handler to open a file with `open`.

To compound the issue, although the handlers are stored in the `com.apple.LaunchServices.plist` preferences accessible via the `defaults` command, the structure of the information (a dictionary with two same level entries, one denoting the protocol, one the handler) makes it non-trivial to parse with `defaults`.

The good news is somebody already solved that problem: HAMsoft Engineering offers the *DefaultApplication* shell utility. [Download it](http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/codeSharing/defaultApplication/defaultApplication.html) and save it somewhere where it is accessible to the shell (typically `/usr/local/bin`, although that is not in the default path for shells on some OS X versions – check the contents of `/etc/paths` to be sure). That available, the following command will open a HTML file in the default browser, whatever editor / viewer might be registered otherwise:

```
open -a "$(/usr/local/bin/DefaultApplication -url 'http:')" "/path/to/your/document.html"
```

Comment: Very nice solution.  What is wrong with simply putting `file:///` in front of the path?

Comment: @QZSupport funny you should ask, as that was my first idea when I set out to answer this, but there are two stumbling stones: 1. needs URL encoding to handle things like spaces in file names and 2. doesn’t work for file paths with a network protocol like `smb:` or `afp:`.

Comment: I would go with the top voted answer because most of us do not change the default settings regarding terminal settings - or whatever setting is responsible here. The default is - as you pointed out correctly - that `open` opens a html with the default browser. You get my vote though

Answer (score 7):

To open the filename.html in the default browser use :

```
open filename.html
```

open is a very good command as well as a feature of Mac OS that makes me fall in love with it more deeper.
It automatically chooses the appropriate default app to open the file.

And in case you want to open a file in your desired app rather then default :

```
open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app filename.html
```

The backslash `\` after Google is used to escape the space character.

Alternatively you can write :

```
open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" filename.html
```

Hope this helps you ( I know I am very late ) and others !!!.

Comment: This is already shown in other answers. Please don't add new answers that just repeat the content from other answers again.

Comment: Honestly I haven't referred any content below. If you felt so I am sorry for that. I am a consistent user of terminal and I already know above commands, so there is no point in copying answers.

Hope you are safe and healthy.
#StayHomeStaySafe

Comment: @wim also **can you point out who has written the code with a backslash escape ?** If there is a question with a narrow scope wrt to scope of knowledge that is going to be used, then they are bound to be  similar. The thing that matters is from which answer you understand the most and also which is well formed.
Thanks for your opinion :)

Answer (score 4):

You can also [get the default browser with Perl](http://daringfireball.net/2009/01/applescripts_targetting_safari_or_webkit): `open http://example.com -a "$(VERSIONER_PERL_PREFER_32_BIT=true perl -MMac::InternetConfig -le 'print +(GetICHelper "http")[1]')"`.

Answer (score 4):

i managed to open the html file with chrome by placing the file after the browser command. so,

```
google-chrome-stable ./index.html
```

although im not sure what the call would be to the default browser, if you knew it you could put it as an alias in your .bashrc and from then on, use whatever you called your alias, plus the file.

```
goo ./index.html
```

just my experience, first response

Answer (score 4):

In terminal you can run open index.html

Answer (score 0):

Install [defaultbrowser](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/defaultbrowser) with [homebrew](https://brew.sh):

```bash
brew install defaultbrowser
```

And then use `defaultbrowser` to get the correct binary name, eg:

```bash
"$(defaultbrowser | grep '*' | awk '{ print $2 }')" https://google.com
```

Answer (score 0):

AsObjC soluition:

```
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

set theHTML to (choose file of type "public.html") as text

set defaultBrowserID to getDefaultBrowserID()
tell application id defaultBrowserID to open theHTML

on getDefaultBrowserID()
    set sharedWorkspace to (current application's NSWorkspace)'s sharedWorkspace()
    set urlNSString to (current application's NSString)'s stringWithString:"http://"
    set testURL to (current application's |NSURL|)'s URLWithString:urlNSString
    set theURL to sharedWorkspace's URLForApplicationToOpenURL:testURL
    set defaultBrowserID to id of application (theURL's |path|() as string)
end getDefaultBrowserID
```

Shell implementation:

```
osascript -e "use AppleScript version \"2.4\" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
use framework \"Foundation\"
use scripting additions

set theHTML to (choose file of type \"public.html\") as text

set defaultBrowserID to getDefaultBrowserID()
tell application id defaultBrowserID to open theHTML

on getDefaultBrowserID()
    set sharedWorkspace to (current application's NSWorkspace)'s sharedWorkspace()
    set urlNSString to (current application's NSString)'s stringWithString:\"http://\"
    set testURL to (current application's |NSURL|)'s URLWithString:urlNSString
    set theURL to sharedWorkspace's URLForApplicationToOpenURL:testURL
    set defaultBrowserID to id of application (theURL's |path|() as string)
end getDefaultBrowserID
"
```

Answer (score -1):

this works on linux, should also work on mac

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# open a html file in default browser, not text editor,
# when text editor is set as default app for html files

url=file:///path/to/file.html

protocol=http

app=$(xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/$protocol)
# example: chromium-browser.desktop

[ -z "$app" ] && {
  echo "error: xdg-mime could not find default app for protocol $protocol"
  exit 1
}

app=$(basename $app .desktop)

gtk-launch $app "$url"
```

ideally i could just say

```
xdg-open http+file:///path/to/file.html
```

but this is not working