# Determine Mac default browser in Python

Tags: python, macos

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10006958/893113) asks how to open an HTML file in the default browser on Mac OS.

There is a [useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12396370/893113) which refers to this infamous bit of Perl:

```
VERSIONER_PERL_PREFER_32_BIT=true perl -MMac::InternetConfig -le 'print +(GetICHelper "http")[1]'
```

Here's some working Python code:

```
import shlex, subprocess

env = {'VERSIONER_PERL_PREFER_32_BIT': 'true'}
raw = """perl -MMac::InternetConfig -le 'print +(GetICHelper "http")[1]'"""
process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(raw), env=env, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = process.communicate()

default_browser = out.strip()
```

Is there a more direct way?

Comment: Read this https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html

Comment: Doesn't work for file URLs.

Comment: Just prefix the path with file://

Comment: To elaborate, given a file URL it has the same problem as `open`: it invokes the default program for html files, which for me is Sublime, not Chrome. There's a good explanation in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10250717/893113

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Python solution using pyobjc:

```
from Foundation import CFPreferencesCopyAppValue

handlers = CFPreferencesCopyAppValue('LSHandlers', 'com.apple.LaunchServices')

try:
    handler = next(x for x in handlers if x.get('LSHandlerURLScheme') == 'http')
    bundle_identifier = handler.get('LSHandlerRoleAll')
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

This returns the bundle identifier, which you can use with the `-b` argument to `open`.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the "property list" file using [plistlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/plistlib.html) from the standard library:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import plistlib

PREFERENCES = (
    Path.home()
    / "Library"
    / "Preferences"
    / "com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist"
)

NAMES = {
    "com.apple.safari": "Safari",
    "com.google.chrome": "Google Chrome",
    "org.mozilla.firefox": "Firefox",
}

with PREFERENCES.open("rb") as fp:
    data = plistlib.load(fp)

for handler in data["LSHandlers"]:
    if handler.get("LSHandlerURLScheme") == "http":
        role = handler["LSHandlerRoleAll"]
        name = NAMES[role]
        print(name)
```